# URL Redirect - Issue after clearing cache (1st time only)

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-8, url-rewrite-module

When trying to enter a site for the first time (after clearing the cache) using the domain name (access.presystem.com), the browser shows an error message: "This site can't be reached".

This issue happens only:

---

1) After clearing the cache in the browser, and
2) when trying to access the website using the domain only (without HTTPS or HTTP).

NOTES:

---

a) If I try to enter to the site using https:// after clearing the cache, it works perfectly.

b) Once I enter the site using https:// for the first time, after clearing the cache, if I try to access the site using the domain name only, it works perfectly...

The Rules created using URL Re-write on IIS are as follows:

---

Requested URL: Matches the Pattern
Using: Regular Expressions
Pattern: (.*)
Ignored case is checked
Condition 1: {HTTPS} Pattern: ^OFF$
Condition 2: {HTTP_HOST} Pattern: ^access.presystem.com$

Action:
Action type: Redirect
Redirect URL: https://{HTTPS_HOST}/{R:1}
Append query string is checked
Redirect type: Permantent (301)

Additional note: Under site bindings, the only one configured is:

---

Type: https
Host Name: access.presystem.com
Port: 443
Ip Address: *

The reason why the type: http with the port 80 is not configured is because I would like users access the site only via https

Finally, this happens with any browser and the web.config file is configured properly.

Any help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Rewriting won't work if your IIS site does not accept HTTP requests at port 80. Add that back please. Otherwise, requests are dropped before rewriting.

Comment: Lex Li, you were right. Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right answer was provided by Lex Li. Thank you Lex. I add this to provide you the credits and mark your answer as the correct one.